# Looking for a website to produce a file using UTM or LL or LL to UTM or general

Tags: gps, arcgis-9.3, batch, file-formats

Is there a website that allows me to upload my GPS file from UTM to lat and long to produce a new output file? I am looking for one to run a batch a list of UTM or LL to convert them in either way.

I am aware of know how to do perfrom this in ArcMap, but what if you wanted  them in a hurry like doing that for ArcGIS Explorer online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the free [DNR Gramin Application](http://www.dnr.state.mn.us/mis/gis/tools/arcview/extensions/DNRGarmin/DNRGarmin.html)?  This should do everything you're after.  [The information at this link](http://www.yssr.nb.ca/Documents/Files/DNR%20Garmin%20User%20Info.pdf) outlines all of its' capabilities & how to use the software.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a website application, but you might take a look at Corpscon, a free application from the US Army Corps of Engineers.  It provides coordinate conversion functions. It will convert text files containing coordinate information from one coordinate system to another.  If your GPS data is in a GIS data format you would need to export it to a coordinate file of some sort.

http://crunch.tec.army.mil/software/corpscon/corpscon.html

Answer (score 0):

Another tool is proj.4
[Documentation is here](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/man_proj), and [homepage is here](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/).  Runs on pc, mac, linux etc.